# softkeyboard is overlapping the textfield

Tags: android

I have a problem where the virtual keyboard is overlapping any input boxes in my app which is frustrating.
I finally figured out that you need to change the config.xml and add the following:

```
    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" /> 
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

but still it is not working

Comment: you should make view (input box) as scrollable.so that when keyboard is opened upper view should scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to had the windowSoftInputMode field in your manifest, like that :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.foo.bar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
....
</activity>
```

This is the field which control the soft keyboard behavior of an acitivity.

If it's not what you want, change the flags. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html for more informations ;). Regards,